# Rituals at Rameswaram before going to Varanasi

Tags: belief, rituals, puja

What rituals to be done at Rameswaram before going to Varanasi ?

And What rituals to be done at Rameswaram after returning from Varanasi ?

Comment: "जे रामेस्वर दरसनु करिहहिं। ते तनु तजि मम लोक सिधरिहहिं॥ **जो गंगाजलु आनि चढ़ाइहि**। सो साजुज्य मुक्ति नर पाइहि॥" So offering Gangajal is one but it's not specified it should be from Varanasi..hence it can be from Badrinath and other places too..

Comment: http://kashirituals.blogspot.com/2014/09/kashi-gaya-prayag-yatra.html?m=1 might be useful...